# asyncio-nats-client-0.11.5 is this compatible with python 3.10.8?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Seeing the following traceback, while doing natsclient.connect with python 3.10.8.

```
  File "/opt/optima/pce_dispatcher/pce_dispatcher.py", line 4213, in run
    await self.nc.connect(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nats/aio/client.py", line 310, in connect
    self._flush_queue = asyncio.Queue(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/queues.py", line 34, in __init__
    super().__init__(loop=loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/mixins.py", line 17, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: As of 3.10, the *loop* parameter was removed from Queue() since it is no longer necessary
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Using Alpine 3.16 which is packaged with 3.10.8.

Appears like asyncio-nats-client-0.11.5 that got published back in Nov 2021.

No idea on how to resolve this unless there is a new version published for 3.10.8 as asyncio have taken some changes related to passing event loop parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It has [already been fixed](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py/commit/4ef58eee92bcfef2e96abff9829dc1e49923ea7a) in the GitHub repo:

> Passing explicit loops to many asyncio apis is deprecated, and
> it is discouraged in general. [...]

...but they seem to have changed the name of the PyPI package. Try `pip install nats-py` for the new version.